# D3 add graticule and geojson

Tags: json, d3.js, geojson, geomap

When adding D3 graticule first and then calling d3.json , the very first feature within json doesn't show on the map. If I add d3.graticule within d3.json after appending paths, graticule will be drawn on top of the features, which is not what I wanted. Here is my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$('.aToolTip').tooltip();
$('.aPopOver').popover();

// D3 Mapping Starts Here
var h = $('#myMap').height();
var w = $('#myMap').width();

console.log("h = " + h , ",  w = " + w);

$('svg').attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h);

var aSVG = d3.select("#aSVGElement");

var aProjection = d3.geo.mercator()
                    .rotate([-135, 24])
                    .scale(600)
                    .translate([w/2, h/2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
                .projection(aProjection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule()
                    .step([10, 10]);

aSVG.append("path")
        .datum(graticule)
        .attr("class", "graticule")
        .attr("d", path);

d3.json("js/Australia.json", function(error, json){

    aSVG.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path);    

}); // end d3.json

});// end document ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first feature doesn't show up if you're drawing the grid first because you're selecting `path`s, of which the grid is one. This means that the first data element (i.e. the first feature) is matched to the existing path and not part of the `.enter()` selection.

To fix this, simply assign a class to your feature `path`s and select accordingly:

```
aSVG.selectAll("path.feature")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "feature")
    .attr("d", path);
```