# d3 multiple different graticules

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a "proper" version of the logo at [IFMMS Logo](http://cms.ifmms.org/images/cms/4/47/Ifmms_banner.gif)
[image: IFMMS Logo]using the graticule feature of d3.js.

At https://gist.run/?id=22361573b05b541ac9799037116aea8d you'll find the current state of the code - specifically version https://gist.run/?id=22361573b05b541ac9799037116aea8d&sha=dd6aef5c64e3ac4c1c917fd5e3c7bbf4b91c75a8

In a loop i am trying to set the graticule steps for different scales of the logo draft.

```js
var lonsteps=6+col*2;
var latsteps=10;
var title='IFMMS Logo';
createLogo(title,id,cx,cy,scale,15,lonsteps,latsteps,debug);
```

in the "createLogo" function i am using these steps as outlined in the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19033063/1497139

I get
[image: Three same graticules]

instead of
[image: 6 steps]
[image: 8 steps]
[image: 10 steps]

so instead of having 6/8/10 steps for the longitudinal grid lines I get three times 6 steps. It seems as if the first setting "overrides" all others although i assign different values.

**What is causing this and how can it be fixed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a parameter (`svgid`) to a function use it and don't use the global variable (`id`) with the same value.

```
function createLogo(title,svgid,cx,cy,scale,strokeScaleFactor,lonsteps,latsteps,debug) {
  // ...
  ggraticule.selectAll("path.feature"+svgid)
  .data(graticule.lines)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "feature"+svgid)
  .attr("d", path);
  // ...
}
```

One indication of the problem can be that your scale is not working.

The reason a HTML ID **should** be unique.

fix it by making the graticule defs id unique and use this new id.

```
  var ggraticule=defs.append("g")
  .attr("id","graticule-"+svgid)
  .attr("class", "graticule")
  .attr("stroke-width",scale/strokeScaleFactor);

  // ...
  use(svg,"graticule-"+svgid);
```

You still have a problem with the background, choose a color and see the effect.

Comment: Thx - it's the simple things that make the difference ...https://gist.run/?id=22361573b05b541ac9799037116aea8d has the change

Answer (score 0):

In D3 v5+ you can [use the step method on your geoGraticules](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#graticule_step) like so:

```
var graticules = d3.geoGraticule().step([15, 15])
```

The default step is 10° and 10° for longitude and latitude.

Comment: thx for the hint. Since the problem is solved this answer might be interesting for others.